# Error installing package of python using pip3

Tags: python-3.x, pip, ubuntu-16.04

Every time I try to install any package using pip3 this error comes.
And when I open python3 in terminal and try to import string module the same error comes. I am not able to figure out any solution for it. My OS version is Ubuntu 16.04.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 9, in <module>
    from pip import main
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    import logging
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/logging/__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    from string import Template
ImportError: No module named 'string'
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 21, in <module>
    from urllib.request import urlopen
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 88, in <module>
    import http.client
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 71, in <module>
    import email.parser
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/email/parser.py", line 12, in <module>
    from email.feedparser import FeedParser, BytesFeedParser
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/email/feedparser.py", line 27, in <module>
    from email import message
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/email/message.py", line 16, in <module>
    from email import utils
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/email/utils.py", line 40, in <module>
    from email.charset import Charset
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/email/charset.py", line 15, in <module>
    import email.quoprimime
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/email/quoprimime.py", line 44, in <module>
    from string import ascii_letters, digits, hexdigits
ImportError: No module named 'string'

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 9, in <module>
    from pip import main
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    import logging
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/logging/__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    from string import Template
ImportError: No module named 'string'
```

Comment: Is `libpython3-all-dev` installed ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem solved since my python 3.5 directory was missing string.py file.